# Add a filtered event trigger on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a filtered event trigger on AWS Lambda but got stuck on how to do this. I'd like to filter by the content of the body of the message. The problem is: this content is inside a list. Here is an exemple of what I'm trying to do:

The body of the message:

```json
{
  "infoA": "foo",
  "infoB": [
    {
      "infoC": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'd like to apply a filter for that lambda execute only when `'infoC' == 'bar'` (my infoB list will always have only one item). My lambda is subscribed to a SQS, so this is why my filter starts with body key. I've already tried the following filter patterns, without success:

```json
{"body": {"infoB": {"infoC": ["bar"]} } }
{"body": {"infoB": [{"infoC": ["bar"]}] } }
{"body": {"infoB[0]": {"infoC": ["bar"]} } }
{"body": {"infoB"[0]: {"infoC": ["bar"]} } }
```

None of this actually worked. On the AWS Lambda documentation, I didn't find information about this kind of filtering (a list inside the body of the message).

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a filtered event trigger the Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Lambda Event Filters then you would need to indicate the position in the array:

```
{
   "Filters": [
        {
            "Pattern": "{ \"infoB[0]\": { \"infoC\": [ \"bar\" ] }}"
        }
    ]
}
```

While I have not tested this, it would be the only option if it works.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUgqGseyltTceWNYpMF_2tXw/how-to-create-dynamo-db-stream-event-filter-for-a-field-from-array-of-objects